# Relation between the eigenvalue of $T$ to the eigenvalue of $p(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$.  Suppose that $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear operator with an eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

> Why is it true that, for every $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$, the scalar $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of the operator $p(T)$ and $v$ is also an eigenvector of $p(T)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $p(\lambda)$?

Comment: (Fixing my errors.)  In the case that $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed, not only that $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(T)$, we also have $$V^{p(\lambda)}\big(p(T)\big)=\bigoplus_{\substack{\mu\in\mathbb{F}\\p(\mu)=p(\lambda)}}\,V^\mu(T)\,.$$  Here, $V^\xi(S)$ denotes the generalized eigenspace of a linear operator $S:V\to V$ associated to an eigenvalue $\xi\in\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: This is a special case of the Spectral Mapping Theorem, fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p = a_0 + a_1 X + ... + a_n X^n$, and $Tv = \lambda v$ ($v \neq 0$), then

$$ p(T) v = a_0 Iv + a_1 Tv + ... + a_n T^n v = a_0v + a_1 \lambda v  + ... + a_n \lambda^n v = p(\lambda) v. $$

This uses the definition of $p(T),$ and $T^n v = \lambda T^{n-1}v = ... = \lambda^n v.$

Comment: ohh so I think I had trouble to understand how does $p(T)v$ is looks like

Comment: By definition, $p(T) = a_0 I + a_1 T + a_2 T^2 + ... + a_n T^n$. Then, I can multiply the whole thing by $v$, simply by using that matrix-vector multiplication distributes over addition of matrices ("working out the brackets"').